# kochat -chatbot : Failed to write core dump. minidumps are not enabled by default on client version of windows

Tags: python, nlp, runtime-error, chatbot

I have this Python I am trying to run using PyCharm.

Here's the code :

```
"""
@auther Hyunwoong
@since 7/1/2020
@see https://github.com/gusdnd852
"""

import os
import platform
import torch
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC

root_dir = os.path.abspath(os.curdir)
# 만약 로딩이 안된다면 root_dir을 직접 적어주세요.
# 데모 기준에서 OS별 root path는 아래와 같이 적으면 됩니다.
# windows : C:Users/yourname/yourdirectory/kochat/demo
# linux : /home/yourname/yourdirectory/kochat/demo

_ = '\\' if platform.system() == 'Windows' else '/'
if root_dir[len(root_dir) - 1] != _: root_dir += _

BASE = {
    'root_dir': root_dir.format(_=_),  # 백엔드 루트경로
    'device': 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu',
    'vector_size': 128,  # 단어 벡터 사이즈
    'batch_size': 512,  # 미니배치 사이즈
    'max_len': 8,  # 문장의 최대 길이 (패드 시퀀싱)
    'delimeter': _,  # OS에 따른 폴더 delimeter

    'PAD': 0,  # PAD 토큰 값 (전체가 0인 벡터)
    'OOV': 1  # OOV 토큰 값 (전체가 1인 벡터)
}

DATA = {
    'data_ratio': 0.8,  # 학습\\검증 데이터 비율
    'raw_data_dir': BASE['root_dir'] + "data{_}raw{_}".format(_=_),  # 원본 데이터 파일 경로
    'ood_data_dir': BASE['root_dir'] + "data{_}ood{_}".format(_=_),  # out of distribution 데이터셋
    'intent_data_dir': BASE['root_dir'] + "data{_}intent_data.csv".format(_=_),  # 생성된 인텐트 데이터 파일 경로
    'entity_data_dir': BASE['root_dir'] + "data{_}entity_data.csv".format(_=_),  # 생성된 엔티티 데이터 파일 경로

    'NER_categories': ['DATE', 'LOCATION', 'RESTAURANT', 'PLACE'],  # 사용자 정의 태그
    'NER_tagging': ['B', 'E', 'I', 'S'],  # NER의 BEGIN, END, INSIDE, SINGLE 태그
    'NER_outside': 'O',  # NER의 O태그 (Outside를 의미)
}

PROC = {
    'logging_precision': 5,  # 결과 저장시 반올림 소수점 n번째에서 반올림
    'model_dir': BASE['root_dir'] + "saved{_}".format(_=_),  # 모델 파일, 시각화 자료 저장 경로
    'visualization_epoch': 50,  # 시각화 빈도 (애폭마다 시각화 수행)
    'save_epoch': 10  # 저장 빈도 (에폭마다 모델 저장)
}

LOSS = {
    'center_factor': 0.025,  # Center Loss의 weighting 비율
    'coco_alpha': 6.25,  # COCO loss의 alpha 값
    'cosface_s': 7.00,  # Cosface의 s값 (x^T dot W를 cos형식으로 바꿀 때 norm(||x||))
    'cosface_m': 0.25,  # Cosface의 m값 (Cosface의 마진)
    'gaussian_mixture_factor': 0.1,  # Gaussian Mixture Loss의 weighting 비율
    'gaussian_mixture_alpha': 0.00,  # Gaussian Mixture Loss의 alpha 값
}

GENSIM = {
    'window_size': 2,  # 임베딩 학습시 사용되는 윈도우 사이즈
    'workers': 8,  # 학습시 사용되는 쓰레드 워커 갯수
    'min_count': 2,  # 데이터에서 min count보다 많이 등장해야 단어로 인지
    'sg': 1,  # 0 : CBOW = 1 \\ SkipGram = 2
    'iter': 2000  # 임베딩 학습 횟수
}

INTENT = {
    'model_lr': 1e-4,  # 인텐트 학습시 사용되는 러닝레이트
    'loss_lr': 1e-2,  # 인텐트 학습시 사용되는 러닝레이트
    'weight_decay': 1e-4,  # 인텐트 학습시 사용되는 가중치 감쇠 정도
    'epochs': 300,  # 인텐트 학습 횟수
    'd_model': 512,  # 인텐트 모델의 차원
    'd_loss': 32,  # 인텐트 로스의 차원 (시각화차원, 높을수록 ood 디텍션이 정확해지지만 느려집니다.)
    'layers': 1,  # 인텐트 모델의 히든 레이어(층)의 수
    'grid_search': True,  # KNN과 Fallback Detector 학습시 그리드 서치 여부

    'lr_scheduler_factor': 0.75,  # 러닝레이트 스케줄러 감소율
    'lr_scheduler_patience': 10,  # 러닝레이트 스케줄러 감소 에폭
    'lr_scheduler_min_lr': 1e-12,  # 최소 러닝레이트
    'lr_scheduler_warm_up': 100,  # 러닝레이트 감소 시작시점

    # auto를 쓰려면 ood dataset을 함께 넣어줘야합니다.
    'distance_fallback_detection_criteria': 'auto',  # [auto, min, mean], auto는 OOD 데이터 있을때만 가능
    'distance_fallback_detection_threshold': -1,  # mean 혹은 min 선택시 임계값
    'softmax_fallback_detection_criteria': 'auto',  # [auto, other], auto는 OOD 데이터 있을때만 가능
    'softmax_fallback_detection_threshold': -1,  # other 선택시 fallback이 되지 않는 최소 값

    # 그리드 서치를 사용하지 않을때 KNN의 K값
    'num_neighbors': 10,

    # 그리드 서치를 사용할 때의 파라미터 목록
    'dist_param': {
        'n_neighbors': list(range(5, 15)),  # K값 범위 설정
        'weights': ["uniform"],  # ['uniform', 'distance']
        'p': [2],  # [1, 2] (맨하튼 vs 유클리디언)
        'algorithm': ['ball_tree']  # ['ball_tree', 'kd_tree']
    },

    # 폴백 디텍터 후보 (선형 모델을 추천합니다)
    'fallback_detectors': [
        LogisticRegression(max_iter=30000),
        LinearSVC(max_iter=30000)
    ]
}

ENTITY = {
    'model_lr': 1e-4,  # 엔티티 학습시 사용되는 모델 러닝레이트
    'loss_lr': 1e-4,  # 엔티티 학습시 사용되는 로스 러닝레이트 (아직 사용되지 않음)
    'weight_decay': 1e-4,  # 엔티티 학습시 사용되는 가중치 감쇠 정도
    'epochs': 1000,  # 엔티티 학습 횟수
    'd_model': 512,  # 엔티티 모델의 차원
    'layers': 1,  # 엔티티 모델의 히든 레이어(층)의 수
    'masking': True,  # loss 계산시 패딩 마스크 여부

    'lr_scheduler_factor': 0.75,  # 러닝레이트 스케줄러 감소율
    'lr_scheduler_patience': 10,  # 러닝레이트 스케줄러 감소 에폭
    'lr_scheduler_min_lr': 1e-12,  # 최소 러닝레이트
    'lr_scheduler_warm_up': 100  # 러닝레이트 감소 시작시점
}

API = {
    'request_chat_url_pattern': 'request_chat',  # request_chat 기능 url pattern
    'fill_slot_url_pattern': 'fill_slot',  # fill_slot 기능 url pattern
    'get_intent_url_pattern': 'get_intent',  # get_intent 기능 url pattern
    'get_entity_url_pattern': 'get_entity'  # get_entity 기능 url pattern
}
```

1. Updating Java to latest version.
2. Update Windows
3. Restart PC
4. Install JPype1 for python 3.6
5. 

When trying to run the following code I get the following error shown in my PyCharm console :

## Here's the error log returned from program executions

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (os_windows_x86.cpp:144), pid=22656, tid=0x0000000000001300
#  guarantee(result == EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION) failed: Unexpected result from topLevelExceptionFilter
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_271-b09) (build 1.8.0_271-b09)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.271-b09 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x000002b7ff973000):  JavaThread "Python Reference Queue" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=4864, stack(0x000000f832910000,0x000000f832b00000)]

Stack: [0x000000f832910000,0x000000f832b00000]
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  0x0000000061e9f6c9
C  0x0000000061de6122
C  0x0000000061de6dcd
C  0x0000000061ddd787
C  0x0000000061e9f34c
C  [ntdll.dll+0xa1eef]
C  [ntdll.dll+0x6aad9]
C  [ntdll.dll+0xa0b5e]
C  0x00000000626e96eb
C  0x00000000626e972b
C  0x0000000062612cd3
C  0x00000000626153ad
C  0x00007ffa81cd414c
C  [python36.dll+0x43f26]
C  [python36.dll+0x43116]
C  [python36.dll+0x43eb9]
C  [python36.dll+0x8e22f]
C  [python36.dll+0x3db17]
C  [python36.dll+0x1a20]
C  [python36.dll+0x1648]
C  [python36.dll+0x1063]
C  0x00007ffa7fe0bfd4
C  0x000002b785b99f4e

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  org.jpype.ref.JPypeReferenceNative.wake()V+0
j  org.jpype.ref.JPypeReferenceQueue$Worker.run()V+42
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
=>0x000002b7ff973000 JavaThread "Python Reference Queue" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=4864, stack(0x000000f832910000,0x000000f832b00000)]
  0x000002b7ff972800 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12580, stack(0x000000f832530000,0x000000f832720000)]
  0x000002b7ff971800 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9968, stack(0x000000f832340000,0x000000f832530000)]
  0x000002b7ff971000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=20076, stack(0x000000f832150000,0x000000f832340000)]
  0x000002b7ff970000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=25116, stack(0x000000f831f60000,0x000000f832150000)]
  0x000002b7ff974000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6600, stack(0x000000f831d70000,0x000000f831f60000)]
  0x000002b784b01800 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=25192, stack(0x000000f831b80000,0x000000f831d70000)]
  0x000002b784b57800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=25708, stack(0x000000f831990000,0x000000f831b80000)]
  0x000002b784ae1000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=24080, stack(0x000000f8317a0000,0x000000f831990000)]
  0x000002b784ad9800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9384, stack(0x000000f8315b0000,0x000000f8317a0000)]
  0x000002b7847a8800 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=20992, stack(0x000000f82ce00000,0x000000f82cff0000)]

Other Threads:
  0x000002b7ff99a800 VMThread [stack: 0x000000f8313c0000,0x000000f8315b0000] [id=26980]
  0x000002b7ff99b000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x000000f832720000,0x000000f832910000] [id=15792]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

heap address: 0x00000000c0000000, size: 1024 MB, Compressed Oops mode: 32-bit
Narrow klass base: 0x0000000000000000, Narrow klass shift: 3
Compressed class space size: 1073741824 Address: 0x0000000100000000

Heap:
 PSYoungGen      total 75776K, used 1300K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x00000000eff80000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 65024K, 2% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000eac45230,0x00000000eea80000)
  from space 10752K, 0% used [0x00000000ef500000,0x00000000ef500000,0x00000000eff80000)
  to   space 10752K, 0% used [0x00000000eea80000,0x00000000eea80000,0x00000000ef500000)
 ParOldGen       total 173568K, used 6075K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000ca980000, 0x00000000eab00000)
  object space 173568K, 3% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000c05eec20,0x00000000ca980000)
 Metaspace       used 4779K, capacity 4984K, committed 5248K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 537K, capacity 603K, committed 640K, reserved 1048576K

Card table byte_map: [0x000002b794f40000,0x000002b795150000] byte_map_base: 0x000002b794940000

Marking Bits: (ParMarkBitMap*) 0x0000000062357fe0
 Begin Bits: [0x000002b7952b0000, 0x000002b7962b0000)
 End Bits:   [0x000002b7962b0000, 0x000002b7972b0000)

Polling page: 0x000002b785b50000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=1984Kb max_used=2010Kb free=243775Kb
 bounds [0x000002b785b80000, 0x000002b785df0000, 0x000002b794b80000]
 total_blobs=704 nmethods=410 adapters=207
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 0.257 Thread 0x000002b7ff970000 nmethod 405 0x000002b785d4bc50 code [0x000002b785d4bd80, 0x000002b785d4bdf8]
Event: 0.357 Thread 0x000002b7ff971000 nmethod 359 0x000002b785d6d2d0 code [0x000002b785d6d6c0, 0x000002b785d72f00]
Event: 15.065 Thread 0x000002b7ff971800  406       3       java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue::reallyPoll (65 bytes)
Event: 15.163 Thread 0x000002b7ff971800 nmethod 406 0x000002b785d6cc10 code [0x000002b785d6cd80, 0x000002b785d6d1f8]
Event: 30.135 Thread 0x000002b7ff971800  407       1       org.jpype.ref.JPypeReferenceQueue::access$100 (5 bytes)
Event: 30.136 Thread 0x000002b7ff971800 nmethod 407 0x000002b785d6c950 code [0x000002b785d6caa0, 0x000002b785d6cb98]
Event: 30.388 Thread 0x000002b7ff971800  408       1       org.jpype.ref.JPypeReferenceQueue::access$200 (5 bytes)
Event: 30.388 Thread 0x000002b7ff971800 nmethod 408 0x000002b785d6c690 code [0x000002b785d6c7e0, 0x000002b785d6c8d8]
Event: 35.903 Thread 0x000002b7ff971800  409   !   3       java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue::remove (125 bytes)
Event: 35.906 Thread 0x000002b7ff971800 nmethod 409 0x000002b785d6b810 code [0x000002b785d6b9e0, 0x000002b785d6c2a0]

GC Heap History (10 events):
Event: 208.510 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=44 (full 22):
 PSYoungGen      total 75776K, used 64K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x00000000eff80000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 65024K, 0% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000eea80000)
  from space 10752K, 0% used [0x00000000ef500000,0x00000000ef510000,0x00000000eff80000)
  to   space 10752K, 0% used [0x00000000eea80000,0x00000000eea80000,0x00000000ef500000)
 ParOldGen       total 173568K, used 6075K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000ca980000, 0x00000000eab00000)
  object space 173568K, 3% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000c05eec20,0x00000000ca980000)
 Metaspace       used 4779K, capacity 4984K, committed 5248K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 537K, capacity 603K, committed 640K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 208.516 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=44 (full 22):
 PSYoungGen      total 75776K, used 0K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x00000000eff80000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 65024K, 0% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000eea80000)
  from space 10752K, 0% used [0x00000000ef500000,0x00000000ef500000,0x00000000eff80000)
  to   space 10752K, 0% used [0x00000000eea80000,0x00000000eea80000,0x00000000ef500000)
 ParOldGen       total 173568K, used 6075K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000ca980000, 0x00000000eab00000)
  object space 173568K, 3% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000c05eec20,0x00000000ca980000)
 Metaspace       used 4779K, capacity 4984K, committed 5248K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 537K, capacity 603K, committed 640K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 276.325 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=45 (full 22):
 PSYoungGen      total 75776K, used 1300K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x00000000eff80000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 65024K, 2% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000eac45230,0x00000000eea80000)
  from space 10752K, 0% used [0x00000000ef500000,0x00000000ef500000,0x00000000eff80000)
  to   space 10752K, 0% used [0x00000000eea80000,0x00000000eea80000,0x00000000ef500000)
 ParOldGen       total 173568K, used 6075K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000ca980000, 0x00000000eab00000)
  object space 173568K, 3% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000c05eec20,0x00000000ca980000)
 Metaspace       used 4779K, capacity 4984K, committed 5248K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 537K, capacity 603K, committed 640K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 276.326 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=45 (full 22):
 PSYoungGen      total 75776K, used 64K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x00000000eff80000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 65024K, 0% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000eea80000)
  from space 10752K, 0% used [0x00000000eea80000,0x00000000eea90000,0x00000000ef500000)
  to   space 10752K, 0% used [0x00000000ef500000,0x00000000ef500000,0x00000000eff80000)
 ParOldGen       total 173568K, used 6075K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000ca980000, 0x00000000eab00000)
  object space 173568K, 3% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000c05eec20,0x00000000ca980000)
 Metaspace       used 4779K, capacity 4984K, committed 5248K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 537K, capacity 603K, committed 640K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 276.326 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=46 (full 23):
 PSYoungGen      total 75776K, used 64K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x00000000eff80000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 65024K, 0% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000eea80000)
  from space 10752K, 0% used [0x00000000eea80000,0x00000000eea90000,0x00000000ef500000)
  to   space 10752K, 0% used [0x00000000ef500000,0x00000000ef500000,0x00000000eff80000)
 ParOldGen       total 173568K, used 6075K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000ca980000, 0x00000000eab00000)
  object space 173568K, 3% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000c05eec20,0x00000000ca980000)
 Metaspace       used 4779K, capacity 4984K, committed 5248K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 537K, capacity 603K, committed 640K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 276.335 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=46 (full 23):
 PSYoungGen      total 75776K, used 0K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x00000000eff80000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 65024K, 0% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000eea80000)
  from space 10752K, 0% used [0x00000000eea80000,0x00000000eea80000,0x00000000ef500000)
  to   space 10752K, 0% used [0x00000000ef500000,0x00000000ef500000,0x00000000eff80000)
 ParOldGen       total 173568K, used 6075K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000ca980000, 0x00000000eab00000)
  object space 173568K, 3% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000c05eec20,0x00000000ca980000)
 Metaspace       used 4779K, capacity 4984K, committed 5248K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 537K, capacity 603K, committed 640K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 276.971 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=47 (full 23):
 PSYoungGen      total 75776K, used 1300K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x00000000eff80000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 65024K, 2% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000eac45230,0x00000000eea80000)
  from space 10752K, 0% used [0x00000000eea80000,0x00000000eea80000,0x00000000ef500000)
  to   space 10752K, 0% used [0x00000000ef500000,0x00000000ef500000,0x00000000eff80000)
 ParOldGen       total 173568K, used 6075K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000ca980000, 0x00000000eab00000)
  object space 173568K, 3% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000c05eec20,0x00000000ca980000)
 Metaspace       used 4779K, capacity 4984K, committed 5248K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 537K, capacity 603K, committed 640K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 276.972 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=47 (full 23):
 PSYoungGen      total 75776K, used 64K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x00000000eff80000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 65024K, 0% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000eea80000)
  from space 10752K, 0% used [0x00000000ef500000,0x00000000ef510000,0x00000000eff80000)
  to   space 10752K, 0% used [0x00000000eea80000,0x00000000eea80000,0x00000000ef500000)
 ParOldGen       total 173568K, used 6075K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000ca980000, 0x00000000eab00000)
  object space 173568K, 3% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000c05eec20,0x00000000ca980000)
 Metaspace       used 4779K, capacity 4984K, committed 5248K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 537K, capacity 603K, committed 640K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 276.972 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=48 (full 24):
 PSYoungGen      total 75776K, used 64K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x00000000eff80000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 65024K, 0% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000eea80000)
  from space 10752K, 0% used [0x00000000ef500000,0x00000000ef510000,0x00000000eff80000)
  to   space 10752K, 0% used [0x00000000eea80000,0x00000000eea80000,0x00000000ef500000)
 ParOldGen       total 173568K, used 6075K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000ca980000, 0x00000000eab00000)
  object space 173568K, 3% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000c05eec20,0x00000000ca980000)
 Metaspace       used 4779K, capacity 4984K, committed 5248K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 537K, capacity 603K, committed 640K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 276.979 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=48 (full 24):
 PSYoungGen      total 75776K, used 0K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x00000000eff80000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 65024K, 0% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000eea80000)
  from space 10752K, 0% used [0x00000000ef500000,0x00000000ef500000,0x00000000eff80000)
  to   space 10752K, 0% used [0x00000000eea80000,0x00000000eea80000,0x00000000ef500000)
 ParOldGen       total 173568K, used 6075K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000ca980000, 0x00000000eab00000)
  object space 173568K, 3% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000c05eec20,0x00000000ca980000)
 Metaspace       used 4779K, capacity 4984K, committed 5248K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 537K, capacity 603K, committed 640K, reserved 1048576K
}

Deoptimization events (7 events):
Event: 0.234 Thread 0x000002b7847a8800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x000002b785d3f894 method=java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.hasNext()Z @ 4
Event: 0.238 Thread 0x000002b7847a8800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x000002b785d5071c method=java.util.Arrays.equals([B[B)Z @ 2
Event: 0.239 Thread 0x000002b7847a8800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x000002b785d4f49c method=com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem.getParent([B)[B @ 21
Event: 0.239 Thread 0x000002b7847a8800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x000002b785d4fc10 method=java.util.Arrays.equals([B[B)Z @ 2
Event: 0.244 Thread 0x000002b7847a8800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x000002b785d47a74 method=java.util.Arrays.hashCode([B)I @ 1
Event: 0.245 Thread 0x000002b7847a8800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x000002b785d49160 method=java.util.LinkedHashMap.linkNodeLast(Ljava/util/LinkedHashMap$Entry;)V @ 11
Event: 0.257 Thread 0x000002b7847a8800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x000002b785d462c0 method=java.util.LinkedHashMap.afterNodeInsertion(Z)V @ 15

Classes redefined (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 0.062 Thread 0x000002b7847a8800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000eabbfe90) thrown at [C:\jenkins\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u271\605\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1512]
Event: 0.070 Thread 0x000002b7847a8800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000eac3a118) thrown at [C:\jenkins\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u271\605\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1512]
Event: 0.070 Thread 0x000002b7847a8800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000eac3a328) thrown at [C:\jenkins\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u271\605\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1512]
Event: 0.070 Thread 0x000002b7847a8800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError': org/jpype/classloader/DynamicClassLoader> (0x00000000eac3a7c0) thrown at [C:\jenkins\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u271\605\hotspot\src\share\vm\classfile\systemDictionary.cpp, line 201]
Event: 0.190 Thread 0x000002b7847a8800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000eaf37e28) thrown at [C:\jenkins\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u271\605\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1512]
Event: 0.190 Thread 0x000002b7847a8800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000eaf38038) thrown at [C:\jenkins\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u271\605\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1512]
Event: 0.191 Thread 0x000002b7847a8800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000eaf3c130) thrown at [C:\jenkins\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u271\605\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1512]
Event: 0.191 Thread 0x000002b7847a8800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000eaf3c340) thrown at [C:\jenkins\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u271\605\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1512]
Event: 0.244 Thread 0x000002b7847a8800 Implicit null exception at 0x000002b785d47952 to 0x000002b785d47a59
Event: 0.245 Thread 0x000002b7847a8800 Implicit null exception at 0x000002b785d49104 to 0x000002b785d49145

Events (10 events):
Event: 207.642 Executing VM operation: ParallelGCSystemGC
Event: 207.650 Executing VM operation: ParallelGCSystemGC done
Event: 207.741 Executing VM operation: ParallelGCSystemGC
Event: 207.749 Executing VM operation: ParallelGCSystemGC done
Event: 208.509 Executing VM operation: ParallelGCSystemGC
Event: 208.516 Executing VM operation: ParallelGCSystemGC done
Event: 276.325 Executing VM operation: ParallelGCSystemGC
Event: 276.335 Executing VM operation: ParallelGCSystemGC done
Event: 276.971 Executing VM operation: ParallelGCSystemGC
Event: 276.979 Executing VM operation: ParallelGCSystemGC done


Dynamic libraries:
0x000000001ca20000 - 0x000000001ca3b000     C:\project\chatterbot\kochat\Scripts\python.exe
0x00007ffaf5700000 - 0x00007ffaf58f0000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x00007ffaf5600000 - 0x00007ffaf56b2000     C:\Windows\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
0x00007ffaf3500000 - 0x00007ffaf37a5000     C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x00007ffaf2b10000 - 0x00007ffaf2c0a000     C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll
0x00007ffaedf00000 - 0x00007ffaedf17000     C:\project\chatterbot\kochat\Scripts\VCRUNTIME140.dll
0x0000000062980000 - 0x0000000062d20000     C:\project\chatterbot\kochat\Scripts\python36.dll
0x00007ffaf5590000 - 0x00007ffaf55e2000     C:\Windows\System32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x00007ffaf5030000 - 0x00007ffaf50ce000     C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll
0x00007ffaf51f0000 - 0x00007ffaf5527000     C:\Windows\System32\combase.dll
0x00007ffaf39e0000 - 0x00007ffaf3aff000     C:\Windows\System32\RPCRT4.dll
0x00007ffaf2c10000 - 0x00007ffaf2c91000     C:\Windows\System32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
0x00007ffaed340000 - 0x00007ffaed34a000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
0x00007ffaf4220000 - 0x00007ffaf4246000     C:\Windows\System32\GDI32.dll
0x00007ffaf2750000 - 0x00007ffaf2771000     C:\Windows\System32\win32u.dll
0x00007ffaf2820000 - 0x00007ffaf29b8000     C:\Windows\System32\gdi32full.dll
0x00007ffaf2780000 - 0x00007ffaf281e000     C:\Windows\System32\msvcp_win.dll
0x00007ffaf3cf0000 - 0x00007ffaf3e84000     C:\Windows\System32\USER32.dll
0x00007ffaf50d0000 - 0x00007ffaf513f000     C:\Windows\System32\WS2_32.dll
0x00007ffaf3f60000 - 0x00007ffaf4003000     C:\Windows\System32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x00007ffaf4010000 - 0x00007ffaf40a7000     C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll

...skip...

0x00007ffaa80f0000 - 0x00007ffaa8143000     C:\project\chatterbot\kochat\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\csgraph\_shortest_path.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
0x00007ffab2420000 - 0x00007ffab2443000     C:\project\chatterbot\kochat\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\csgraph\_tools.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
0x00007ffaa8800000 - 0x00007ffaa8822000     C:\project\chatterbot\kochat\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\csgraph\_traversal.cp36-win_amd64.pyd

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -ea -Xmx1024m 
java_command: <unknown>
java_class_path (initial): C:\project\chatterbot\kochat\lib\site-packages\konlpy\java;C:\project\chatterbot\kochat\lib\site-packages\konlpy\java\bin;C:\project\chatterbot\kochat\lib\site-packages\konlpy\java\*;C:\project\chatterbot\kochat\lib\site-packages\konlpy\java\jhannanum-0.8.4.jar;C:\project\chatterbot\kochat\lib\site-packages\konlpy\java\kkma-2.0.jar;C:\project\chatterbot\kochat\lib\site-packages\konlpy\java\aho-corasick.jar;C:\project\chatterbot\kochat\lib\site-packages\konlpy\java\shineware-common-1.0.jar;C:\project\chatterbot\kochat\lib\site-packages\konlpy\java\shineware-ds-1.0.jar;C:\project\chatterbot\kochat\lib\site-packages\konlpy\java\komoran-3.0.jar;C:\project\chatterbot\kochat\lib\site-packages\konlpy\java\snakeyaml-1.12.jar;C:\project\chatterbot\kochat\lib\site-packages\konlpy\java\scala-library-2.12.3.jar;C:\project\chatterbot\kochat\lib\site-packages\konlpy\java\open-korean-text-2.1.0.jar;C:\project\chatterbot\kochat\lib\site-packages\konlpy\java\twitter-text-1.14.7.jar;C:\project\chatterbot\kochat\lib\site-packages\konlpy\java\*
Launcher Type: generic

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_271
PATH=C:\project\chatterbot\kochat\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Anaconda3;C:\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Python38\Scripts\;C:\Python38\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Users\yc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\;C:\Users\yc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\;C:\Users\yc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\;C:\Users\yc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\;C:\Users\yc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\yc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\;C:\Users\yc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\yc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Shell 8.0\bin\;C:\Users\yc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\;C:\Users\yc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\;C:\Users\yc\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\yc\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\yc\.dotnet\tools;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.3.1\bin;;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.3.1\bin;;C:\Users\yc\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\project\flask1;C:\venvs;;C:\project\chatterbot\kochat\lib\site-packages\numpy\.libs;C:\project\chatterbot\kochat\lib\site-packages\scipy\.libs
USERNAME=yc
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 165 Stepping 5, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 10.0 , 64 bit Build 18362 (10.0.18362.1350)

CPU:total 12 (initial active 12) (6 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 165 stepping 5, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, avx2, aes, clmul, erms, 3dnowpref, lzcnt, ht, tsc, tscinvbit, bmi1, bmi2, adx

Memory: 4k page, physical 16635964k(2881188k free), swap 32405488k(5223724k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.271-b09) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_271-b09), built on Sep 16 2020 19:14:59 by "" with MS VC++ 15.9 (VS2017)

time: Fri Mar  5 14:23:33 2021
timezone: ´eCN¹I±¹ C￥AØ½A
elapsed time: 278.430110 seconds (0d 0h 4m 38s)
```

Comment: And what does this have to do with Java?

Comment: sorry..I don't know how to fix it, but there was a tag that copied the java runtime error as it was.